# Узнать все доступные раскладки (языки) пользователя

Tags: java, android, input, multilanguage

Есть способ узнать текущий язык системы пользователя через Locale, существует ли способ узнать все доступные раскладки (языки)? Пример для наглядности, на многих устройствах при зажатии клавиши "пробел" можно выбрать язык ввода из уже выбранных до этого. Как узнать эти языки?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759507/android-get-list-of-supported-locales

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ссылка интересная, но не подходит, там просто идет перевод на текущий язык системы всех getAvailableLocales(). Вопрос именно в том, как получить эти два языка пользователя, когда зажимается "пробел" для выбора раскладки клавиатуры.

Comment: Тогда это вам должно помочь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39639103/5479247